# Laravel checkout page total price not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying for hours to solve the issue

Controller

```
public function index(){

    $carts=DB::table('carts')->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $cartcount=DB::table('carts')->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->count();
    $totalprice = DB::table('carts')
    ->join('products', 'products.id', '=' , 'carts.product_id')
    ->where('user_id', '=' , Auth::user()->id )
    ->select('products.price')
    ->get();
    return view('frontend.checkout',compact('carts','cartcount','totalprice'));

}
```

blade:

```
  <p style="color:black;">Total <span class="price" style="color:black"><b> {{ $totalprice }} </b></span></p>
```

I dont know how to get the price only and add the product prices together, help will be highly appreciated

[check issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97QZD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$totalprice = DB::table('carts')
->join('products', 'products.id', '=' , 'carts.product_id')
->where('user_id', '=' , Auth::user()->id )
->sum('products.price');
```